# RiverPod - How to await using FutureProvider on AsyncValue not in widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, riverpod

I need to get 1 field 1 time from Firebase Cloud Firestore. How do I accomplish this with providers outside of Widget build?

Below are my combined providers. `appStartupProvider` is a FutureProvider and I want to get the `bool` value from this 1 field in firestore. However, the await in `appStartupProvider` states "'await' applied to 'AsyncValue', which is not a 'Future'".

```
final accountStreamProvider = StreamProvider<Account>((ref) {
  final database = ref.watch(databaseProvider);
  return database != null ? database.accountStream() : const Stream.empty();
});

final _accountSetupCompleteProvider = Provider<AsyncValue<bool>>((ref) {
  return ref
      .watch(accountStreamProvider)
      .whenData((account) => account?.accountSetupComplete ?? false);
});

final appStartupProvider = FutureProvider<bool>((ref) async {
  final accountSetupComplete = await ref.watch(_accountSetupCompleteProvider);

  return accountSetupComplete;
});
```

Obviously missing some key knowledge here on combing providers and AsyncValue, but I'm trying to accomplish the situation stated on [RiverPod Combining Providers](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers) page, where I see await is being used.

[image]

Comment: Did you sort this out? I am currently learning flutter and I have the same issue with the riverpod providers. I would like to resolve the return value of the provider so I can use the value in another one but can't find out proper way to do it.

Comment: @groo See my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66955043/7259858

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The example in the documentation was incorrect at the time of your post. It has since been updated and is now correct.

This is how you could write it:

```dart
final accountStreamProvider = StreamProvider<Account?>((ref) {
  final database = ref.watch(databaseProvider);
  return database != null ? database.accountStream() : const Stream.empty();
});

final _accountSetupCompleteProvider = FutureProvider<bool>((ref) async {
  final account = await ref.watch(accountStreamProvider.last);
  return account?.accountSetupComplete ?? false;
});

final appStartupProvider = FutureProvider<bool>((ref) async {
  final accountSetupComplete = await ref.watch(_accountSetupCompleteProvider.future);
  return accountSetupComplete;
});
```

Or:

```dart
final accountStreamProvider = StreamProvider<Account?>((ref) {
  final database = ref.watch(databaseProvider);
  return database != null ? database.accountStream() : const Stream.empty();
});

final _accountSetupCompleteProvider = Provider<AsyncValue<bool>>((ref) {
  return ref
      .watch(accountStreamProvider)
      .whenData((account) => account?.accountSetupComplete ?? false);
});

final appStartupProvider = Provider<bool>((ref) {
  final accountSetupComplete = ref.watch(_accountSetupCompleteProvider).maybeWhen(
        data: (data) => data, 
        orElse: () => false,
      );

  return accountSetupComplete;
});
```

Answer (score 20):

`await` usage is available via:

- `.future` on `FutureProvider` [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/FutureProvider/future.html)
- `.last` on `StreamProvider` [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/StreamProvider/last.html)

example

```
final carsListFutureProvider = FutureProvider<List<Car>>((ref) {
  final backend = ref.watch(backendProvider);
  return backend.getList(pathName, (json) => Car.fromJson(json));
});

final carFutureProvider = FutureProvider.family<Car?,int>((ref,id) async {
  final list = await ref.watch(carsListFutureProvider.future);
  return list.firstWhereOrNull((e) => e.id == id);
});
```

It seems that at the moment the documentation contains incorrect code examples. [issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/411)